# Flask-Security example does not work

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I edited the app.py file to only use MongoDB through MongoEngine(you get to choose MongoDB or SQL). This is the output when I try to run my app:

```
    Familys-imac:flask-security Paul-Arthur$ python app.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "app.py", line 17, in <module>
        from flask.ext.security.datastore import MongoEngineUserDatastore
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/exthook.py", line 86, in load_module
        raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
    ImportError: No module named flask.ext.security.datastore.MongoEngineUserDatastore
```

This to me seams to suggest that there is a problem with the MongoEngine (please note that this is in a virtualenv).

I therefor try to re-install the package, thinking that this might be the problem but I have no luck with that too. Output seams perfectly normal, what is happening?

```
    familys-imac:flask-security Paul-Arthur$ pip install MongoEngine
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): MongoEngine in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pymongo in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from MongoEngine)
    Cleaning up...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQLAlchemy, you'd import it as:

> from flask.ext.security.datastore.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyUserDatastore

I think Mongo would be:

> from flask.ext.security.datastore.mongoengine import MongoEngineUserDatastore

Comment: You can see it in an example on Flask API page http://packages.python.org/Flask-Security/: from flask.ext.mongoengine import MongoEngine
from flask.ext.security.datastore.mongoengine import MongoEngineUserDatastore